# How to solve this Third Order PDE using NDSolve; Showing some missing variable error

Tags: differential-equations, difference-equations, education, code

I just confuse why ***u[0,t]==Sin[\omega *t] cannot be used as a variable* error was showing

````
\[Beta] = 1;
\[Alpha] = 1;
ic = {u[y, 0] == 0};
bc = {u[0, t] == Sin[\[Omega]*t], (D[u[y, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0};
pde1 = D[u[y, t], t] + \[Alpha]*D[u[y, t], {t, 2}] == 
   D[u[y, t], {y, 2}] + \[Beta]*D[u[y, t], t, y, y];
NDSolve[pde1, ic, bc, u, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]```
````

Comment: First you are using `NDSolve` so everything you aren't solving for needs to have been assigned a numeric value and your Omega has no numeric value. If I insert `Omega=2;` that makes that error go away. Second you get new errors. The docs show `NDSolve[eqns,funs,vars]`, not `NDSolve[equs,condition1,condition2,funs,vars]` If you change your input to `Beta=1;Alpha=1;Omega=1;
NDSolve[{D[u[y,t],t]+Alpha*D[u[y,t],{t,2}]==D[u[y,t],{y,2}]+Beta*D[u[y,t],t,y,y],u[y,0]==0,
u[0,t]==Sin[Omega*t],(D[u[y,t],t]/.t->0)==0},u,{y,0,1},{t,0,1}]` then it complains inconsistent conditions and needs more eqns

Comment: @Bill Question remains, which "Method" and missing "BoundaryConditions" the Mathematica solution uses. It isn't "FiniteElement" or "MethodOfLines".

Comment: ```\[Omega] = 10;
\[Beta] = 0.2;
\[Alpha] = 0.1;
ic = {u[y, 0] == 0, (D[u[y, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0};
bc = {u[0, t] == Cos[\[Omega]*t], u[1, t] == 0};
pde1 = D[u[y, t], t] + \[Alpha]*D[u[y, t], {t, 2}] == 
   D[u[y, t], {y, 2}] + \[Beta]*D[u[y, t], t, y, y];
NDSolve[{pde1, ic, bc}, u, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MinPoints" -> 50, "MaxPoints" -> 50},
      Method -> {"IDA", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"GMRES"}}}]```    What BCs are further need ? I tried many time but can't get any idea, any help please.